# How to enable automatic updation in entity framework when database changes in Database first approach?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, database, entity-framework

How to enable automatic updation in entity framework when database changes for eg- Change in table structure , new stored procedure added etc.

Entity framework i.e edmx should automatically take changse update from database when we build.